# How to set in Silverlight WebClient timeout?

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, webclient

I use WebClient in a Silverlight Appliction to access REST Services. Its an unknown amount of asynchronous calls. 
The cool thing is, you can order your requests and responses!  the responses are matched to theirs requests! This is necessary, because you do not know in what order the responses will come back.

But how do i get a "timeout" for my calls with WebClient? lets say 15 sec
I would like kinda to stick to WebClient/this code with delegates/lambda. I know there is a timeout property with WebRequest class, but i am not sure if just can replace WebClient with WebRequest but keep the functionality.

```
int maxRequests = list_S.Count;
// amount of URI
        foreach (string item in list_S)
        {
            bool isValid = Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(item, UriKind.Absolute);
            Uri uriTest;
            if(isValid) //if it is valid Uri, send request
            {
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
                {
                    if (args.Error == null)
                    {
                        dict.Add((int)args.UserState, args.Result);

                    }
                    //here you test if it is the last request... if it is, you can
                    //order the list and use it as you want 
                    if (dict.Count == maxRequests)
                    {
                        var orderedResults = dict.OrderBy(a => a.Key);
                    }
                    closeTabitem_SensorSource();
                };
                wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(item), i++);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Uri FAIL!: " + item);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `WebRequest` does not provide a means for managing request timeouts either.

The approach you need to take is to use `WebClient` in conjunction with your own code based on a `DispatcherTimer` that will call the `WebClient` `CancelAsync` method.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there's a timeout built in (something around 30 seconds, from memory.)  So this approach would work if you wanted a shorter timeout, but not if you want a longer one.

Comment: @Drew: I think you are mistaken.  Testing with a delay of 5 minutes on the server I could not get either BrowserHttp nor the ClientHttp stack to timeout.  Of course there could be all manner of other devices between the client and the code on server causing the delay which may intervene and throw a timeout.  However it doesn't appear the Silverlight has a built-in timeout or if it does its probably excessively large.  30 seconds would be a bit stingy.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones, thanks for correcting me on this.  It's relevant to what I'm working on right now, so that's very helpful.